# Ubuntu 22.04: Firefox unable to load module

Tags: permissions, firefox, smartcard

### Firefox is unable to load module

I've been trying to setup a smartcard reading device, and I've gotten stuck twice on the same place.

When it comes to configuring the Security Device on Firefox, I can't access the `.so` file. Firefox merely shows the error "Alert: Unable to add module", but I've noticed that when I try to browse my files manually, trying to access the `/usr` directory returns an error (sometimes, I seem to not be able to get it consistently).

It also happens that the software I installed for the digital certificate tried to open an html with Firefox, which is located in `/usr/share/`, and Firefox doesn't seem to be able to load that either. It returns a "Can't open file".

### Steps followed

1. Open Firefox
2. Settings → Privacy and Security → Security Devices → Load
3. Insert path `/usr/lib/libpkcs11-dnie.so` and try to load (yes, I've checked that the file does actually exist)
4. Receive `Alert: Unable to add module` error

### Relevant information

- Ubuntu 22.04
- I'm on the latest snap version of Firefox: 100.0.1-1
- Trying to setup the digital certificate for my Spanish ID (DNIe)

Comment: The SNAP version of Firefox has its problems. Remove the SNAP version and switch to the apt/deb version.

Comment: I have a same problem, unable to access to /usr/lib/ or /usr/share when I access from Firefox.

Comment: I tried installing the apt/deb version and the exact same thing still happens. No luck so far.

Comment: @JanaL In Ubuntu, the `deb` version actually installs the Snap underneath... so if you want to use a "real" .deb package, it shouldn't be the one coming from Canonical.

Comment: @JanaL I can confirm that installing the Firefox version from the binary allowed me to load the `/usr/lib/libpkcss11-dni.so` successfully. Using the snap version or the flathub version didn't work at all. You can check this guide about how to install Firefox without any package manager: https://support.mozilla.org/ca/kb/Instal%C2%B7laci%C3%B3%20del%20Firefox%20a%20Linux#firefox:linux:fx110

Comment: Another option (confirmed working) is to install firefox-esr (Extended Support Release) instead of the standard Firefox. In fact many current distributions like Debian come with that version. I have set up a tutorial for my students here https://bytes.cat/apache_dnie#resolucio_amb_ubuntu_2204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is thanks to a comment and blog post from [Enric Mieza](https://askubuntu.com/users/1001283/enric-mieza))

The problem is the Snap version of Firefox from Ubuntu 22.04. Installing the Extended Support Release of Firefox fixes this (`firefox-esr`).

To do this in an Ubuntu 22.04 system, follow the next steps (make sure to have admin privileges):

1. Remove the snap version of Firefox with:

```bash
snap remove firefox
```

2. Add the [PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-ppa.html.en) from the Mozilla team and install the ESR version of Firefox:

```bash
apt install software-properties-common -y
add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
apt install firefox-esr
```

3. (Optionally) Add a symbolic link to the `firefox-esr` binary so that it properly opens the installation instructions included in the `libpkcs11-dnie` package:

```bash
ln -s /usr/bin/firefox-esr /usr/bin/firefox
```